# Add result from a function in a HTML form

Tags: wordpress

I have the following PHP code which is a template page for a wordpress site:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Calculator Form
*/
get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="grid_7 suffix_1 <?php echo of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos') ?>">
<FORM action="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/function.php" method="post">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="" style="width:200px;" />
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Calculate" style="width:200px;" />
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="result" VALUE="" disabled style="width:200px;" />
</FORM>
</div><!--#content-->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

For arguments sake, let's say that the function.php file looks like:

```
<?php 
    function calculate($value)
    {
        return $value / 1000;
}
calculate($_POST['inputbox']);
?>
```

I want to add the result of this function into the result field in the form.

Comment: Try at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a WordPress thing. If I were doing this, I would avoid the functions.php and either use some Javascript to output the calculation or PHP within the template to display the result. Since you are leaning more toward PHP:

```
<?php
    if( $_POST['submit'] ) :
        $result = $_POST['inputbox'] / 1000;
    else :
        $result = "";
    endif;
?>
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="inputbox" value="" style="width:200px;" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate" style="width:200px;" />
    <input type="text" name="result" value="" disabled style="width:200px;" />
    <input type="text" name="result" value="<?php echo $result; ?>" disabled style="width:200px;" />
</form>
```

(Untested)